# Next.js standalone not reading env file

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables

I have a question about my Next.js project.

I have configured my project to be build over the [standalone mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files-experimental) for the deployment

```
experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true
}
```

Using this, it generates me a standalone folder with a `server.js` like expected.

The main issue is that I am using an env variable in my sources, called `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL`

When I start my project in development mode (using `next serve`), it works fine.

But when I start the standalone generated file (using `node server.js`) it does not work.

It seems that the file is loaded on the "server side", when I `console.log` its value in the `.next/standalone/server/pages/_app.js` it shows the right value in the node console.

But it looks like next is using files under `.next/static/chunks/pages/` and an other app.js that does not seem to access process.env (on browser side).

I thought that prefixing my env var with `NEXT_PUBLIC` was meant to work this way, it seems not.

Any idea on how it works there ?

Comment: Could you open up a GitHub issue with a reproduction and we can look into it? Thank you!

Comment: Running into this issue as well, any updates?

Comment: For what it worth, we found out (reading docs and looking at the code) that the variables are replaced by their values at compile time.
So there is now way to achieve that.
The workaround we found is to use a env.json in the public (static) folder that contains all of our variables and that is replaces for deployments.

Answer (score -8):

On your build server, create the file name ".env" and put all of your environments.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=https://api.example.com
```

please refer [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)